# SQL - fixing Join issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like below.

```sql
select   c.relname as Table,ex.location as path,
case when ex.fmttype='t' then 'text' when ex.fmttype='c' then 'csv'
else 'Unknown' end as format, case when ex.writable='0' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as is_readonly
from pg_exttable ex 
join pg_class c on ex.reloid=c.oid;
```

On the table pg_exttable I have a column called `reloid`. I want to add a new column in this query from another table. On the other table the column `oid` can be a join condition.

So I tried this query.

```sql
select  ns.nspname as schema,c.relname as Table,ex.location as path,
case when ex.fmttype='t' then 'text' when ex.fmttype='c' then 'csv'
else 'Unknown' end as format, case when ex.writable='0' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as is_readonly
from pg_exttable ex 
join pg_class c on ex.reloid=c.oid 
join pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns on ex.reloid=ns.oid  ;
```

But its giving 0 rows. I dont know where is the issue with this join.

Comment: I'm not an expert in postgresql, but likely your join condition is invalid. Are you sure that the valid criteria? The doc here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/catalog-pg-namespace.html speak about a reference to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/catalog-pg-authid.html . And here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/catalog-pg-class.html, there is no `reloid`. But a `relowner`.

Comment: Its actually greenplum (using very older version of Postgres)

Comment: Does `left join` produce any rows?

Comment: Obviously, there exist no pg_exttable rows for which both exist pg_class and pg_catalog rows the oid of which matches pg_exttable.reloid. Check your data to verify this. Decide whether this is actually the criteria you want or which other criteria you need instead.